# Haskell Typeable instance

Tags: haskell, types, instance, deriving

I'm using `cmdargs` to get some arguments from a command line program. I'm using some special type in my program

```
data Function = Max
              | Min
              | Moy
              | Med
              deriving (Eq,Data,Typeable)
```

I can pass these types directly in arguments with `"Max" "Min" "Moy" "Med"` by deriving the `Function` datatype in the classes `Data` and `Typeable`. My problem is my program is becoming more complex and I need to rename my constructor to avoid name collisions.

```
data Function = funMax
              | funMin
              | funMoy
              | funMed
              deriving (Eq,Data,Typeable)
```

However, I would like to keep accessing these constructor with `"Max" "Min" "Moy" "Med"`. To do that, I suppose I need to create my own `Data` and `Typeable` Instances of `Function`, is that right ?

My problem is I didn't manage to create these instance even after reading the Hackage documentation.

**Have you ever succesfully created `Data` and `Typeable` instances of your own data type?**

Comment: I'm confused. Are you using `DataKinds` and promoting those constructors or something?

Comment: I can't understand this question. You want to give them different names to avoid name clashes, yet you want to access them with the old names. This looks contradictory to me. How do you expect this will work, exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In recent versions of GHC, `Typeable` simply cannot be user-defined. Its casting operations are supposed to be guaranteed safe, and for that only automatically derived instances are allowed.

Since GHC 7.10, it's changed further: `Typeable` is now automatically derived for *all* types, so `deriving Typeable` is actually redundant (but may be included for backwards compatibility.)

`Data` *can* still be user-defined, but I'm not sure it's a good idea. In fact for your use case I'm suspecting it would be better to use the much simpler `Read` class instead.

You can also avoid renaming your constructors by splitting them off into a different module, and importing that qualified:

```
module Types.Fun where
data Function = Max
              | Min
              | Moy
              | Med
              deriving (Eq,Data,Typeable)

...

module Main where
import qualified Types.Fun as Fun

... case ... of Fun.Max -> ...
```